# How to color each week of calendar from Sat to Fri in different colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Im using this [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and
I manage to do on select to select whole week from Sat to Fri but also im looking to color each week from Sat to Fri in different colors, but have no idea how to do it

or even on hover to color the week from Sat to Fri will do the job

```js
// clear value of input
    $('#weeklyDatesPicker').on('focus', function(){
      $(this).val('');
    })


        moment.updateLocale('en', {
          week: { dow: 1 },
          useCurrent: false
        });

      //Initialize the datePicker
      $("#weeklyDatesPicker").datetimepicker({
          format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
      });

       //Get the value of Start and End of Week
      $('#weeklyDatesPicker').on('dp.change', function (e) {
          var value = $("#weeklyDatesPicker").val();
          var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(-1).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
          var lastDate =  moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(5).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
          $("#weeklyDatesPicker").val(firstDate + " / " + lastDate);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
 
                <input class="form-control" type='text' id='weeklyDatesPicker' placeholder="" />
              </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.datepicker tbody tr:nth-child(n)` selector, `n` from `1-6` for six rows

```js
// clear value of input
$('#weeklyDatesPicker').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).val('');
})


moment.updateLocale('en', {
  week: {
    dow: 1
  },
  useCurrent: false
});

//Initialize the datePicker
$("#weeklyDatesPicker").datetimepicker({
  format: 'MM-DD-YYYY'
});

//Get the value of Start and End of Week
$('#weeklyDatesPicker').on('dp.change', function(e) {
  var value = $("#weeklyDatesPicker").val();
  var firstDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(-1).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
  var lastDate = moment(value, "MM-DD-YYYY").day(5).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
  $("#weeklyDatesPicker").val(firstDate + " / " + lastDate);
});
```

```css
.datepicker tbody tr:nth-child(1) {
  background: orange;
}

.datepicker tbody tr:nth-child(2) {
  background: purple;
}

.datepicker tbody tr:nth-child(3) {
  background: teal;
}

.datepicker tbody tr:nth-child(4) {
  background: yellow;
}

.datepicker tbody tr:nth-child(5) {
  background: cyan;
}

.datepicker tbody tr:nth-child(6) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group col-md-12">

  <input class="form-control" type='text' id='weeklyDatesPicker' placeholder="" />
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you did not get it but weeks should be colored from saturday to friday like this 03-07-2020 / 03-13-2020

Comment: Well you could set the `dow: 6` in `updateLocale` if you want coloring from those days. But to keep the days starting from Monday and get colors from Sat to Fri, you will need to individually select days. There is no straightforward solution in that case.